# ExactOnline: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: exact-online

I'm trying to connect to ExactOnline server using HttpWebRequest from C#. When I try to get the Response, I get an exception: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

The Web Request looks like:

Method: GET

Address: "https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/3175257/Logistics/Items?$select=Code&$top=1"

Accept: application/json

ContentType: application/json

Authorization: "Bearer access_token"

where access_token looks like:
"stampNL001.gAAAAGivCOkntSKiT0xYatuOkLEkbA0cCcPAbdDZGctQSAHRuaJ1KfvMY1QjnKWLM4BnRNRh8Vpg9H-3ISW6Vs1Xr0EXjHxgxH1o-n4BJAySMw1tCF-v9heoQ_vQjS2zz8SZtYj1OT9U8DSJnvKzdd6dVKN90G3NA6k80EiS95wgxsVSBAIAAIAAAADO4MGzvH-iyio7XsXArprV_ey-zH9H-NPT2n4CBbjlIJ8gIkjLFvXrcJrZ2lwUBFOrgaHQwfU8dvmnSyRRzlZEe9wSfcpX16BPB7tZzrR_mdQozAtgWVxtIdzxUIHlqaFk0BNhOIfMdDxnagivTdo3HNdTVg9N8K0lx-TX4aNeeoRgzMho46Z1ix1te6rJ8_GjJeAjl7iyVDYqoK_D2Zlaa6cIYNillNlaOYxV2e95tcKoMLPRKUx3ULBtht_joijvA8raWhNBxHiJZQsIyCbTCJuC-dARqicrbdOqNkv769oRgnhLokWHt44dLpwQJ990eWqj1R6ppmF-W5s6d5EpQsLqkFSiPtpIHkao3D4Yxv6BCD8bhsjfjwAiISyyIPt7GbVv4OPZ7dDTMBZbWJBX2JLPWsxiPqb1Y1dOUPMxfFty9mM22qBXq8VA3EyA96-JwNqgIy4eP5hbXmeEU-BOxnF4vp_dZEZU-iM5fV-uYjZYduVtMNBHW-ubQZ811_rv1trx0TP7eEz8dbcfNlB0uAcb6NR-5tC2qwV0wb59qOjO2HQhb0TKGslPjefjwyhNK4ZVSWL0Cr_1KzxpKjA1suY12gBv_J6vQ4js3dlW1MxwypJaUzMMBvtGPqS2N3zcLvrMth1wiB7IjxfA5jd3hRo5_F3iCLTeDtLxToKpNA"

The same code (same input) worked two weeks ago.

What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the response of this endpoint, if you query it without $filter. look at the following screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpJEZ.jpg it shows your endpoint call. it gives an error 400 bad request and states the answer to your problem: $filter is required for this endpoint.

Now look at this screenshot with $filter added https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzbdQ.jpg it gives back data without errors. i don't have any logistics data to show but it shows i don't have any and no error.

More in depth:

It looks like $filter has started to become an enforced required addition to certain endpoints. It was stated as 'required' for over a year, but just recently they started to actively block queries without the $filter parameter (speaking from experience).

[From the release notes from august 2021](https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-ReleaseNote-rn-2107-rn-appcenter-mandatoryfiltering):

> Mandatory filtering for properties on 14 REST API endpoints To help
> keep API traffic in Exact Online running efficiently, we have made
> filtering mandatory for several properties within 12 API endpoints.
> Filtering helps ensure that only relevant data is retrieved when you
> make API calls, so you don’t have to work with a large amount of data.

PS. I post this as a new answer since my original answer was swiftly hidden end subsequently deleted (within an hour) by many mods. Corrections/changes to that answer on the other hand are not reviewed as spediently. Still waiting a day later. Since i think i am correct in my answer (i recently had to deal with the same issue on some code that had been running just fine for many months) i post it as a separate and new answer, for anyone looking for a real answer to the same issue.